# jw player 6 how to use a combination of both hd cc

Tags: jwplayer

How is it possible to  use a combination of both HD and CC in JW Player 6?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you would need to use a combination of these two examples:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29248/sd-and-hd-qualities

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29360/basic-vtt-captions

Hope that helps!

Comment: How do I use both at the same video?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking.

Comment: I would say, first video in HD as well as the subtitle option and can not be used at the same time right?

Comment: Yes, they can. If you combine both of the examples I provided above together, it will work. Did you even try it? There was a reason your original post was down voted.

Comment: I provided full code in a 2nd answer, it works fine. There you go.

Comment: In fact, I checked your link out, it works fine, and it is a black bg on white text, exactly expected.

Comment: using this code. Change the background color and the opening video, and subtitles, but is shaded. http://b1303.hizliresim.com/17/c/kz6y9.jpg

Comment: It looks like this is a bug. I can't get the background to go away either. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: http://b1303.hizliresim.com/17/c/kz6y9.jpg this code not work google chrome and yandex browser

Comment: 1) No idea what Yandex is.
2) In your code, under this line - width: 1075,

Add - primary: "flash",

Comment: No Problem! Glad you got it.

Comment: jw player 6 how to play .m3u8 file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code of this actually working. All I did was combine the two examples that I provided above, so yes, it works, if you actually try it.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.longtailvideo.com/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
<p><div id="container"></div></p>
<script>
jwplayer("container").setup({
  playlist: [{
    image: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/thumbs/i8oQD9zd-640.jpg",
    sources: [{
      file: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/i8oQD9zd-DZ7jSYgM.mp4",
      width: 1280,
      height: 720
    },{
      file: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/i8oQD9zd-kNspJqnJ.mp4",
      width: 640,
      height: 360
    }],
    captions: [{
      file: 'http://www.longtailvideo.com/sites/default/files/jw6-captions.vtt',
      label: 'English'
    }]
  }]
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about the subtitle color? You need to be more specific.

Comment: <div id='player_93466'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  jwplayer('player_93466').setup({
    width: "1075",
    height: "624",
    primary: "flash",
      playlist: [{
        image: "1920x1080_4140x160.mp4",
        captions: [
          { file: "_h924657-cap2ttml.xml", label: "English" }
        ]
      }],
      captions: {
        back: false,
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        fontsize: 12
      }
    });
</script>

Comment: I would style it has per - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28845/adding-video-captions, I already checked your link and it works fine.

Comment: jw player 6 how to play .m3u8 file?

Comment: Not possible. It is a premium only feature. If you have any further questions about the player and the specific features it should be done on the LongTail website, as your specific question you posted on StackOverflow was answered already, and this is not a discussion forum for every single JW Player related question...

Comment: how to add this code subtitle and screenshot picture im using wordpress

Comment: i found preview pictures here : http://tw.trlr.us/teen-wolf-season-2-ep-1-omega-full-episode/ im searching this post how add subtitles ?

Comment: Please contact us through - http://www.longtailvideo.com/contact-us, your original question was already answered here.  If you have any further questions about the player and the specific features it should be done on the LongTail website, as your specific question you posted on StackOverflow was answered already, and this is not a discussion forum for every single JW Player related question.